# DSL modem show 24Mbps speed, I get 1Mpbs

Tags: internet-speed, dsl-modem

My D-Link DSL modem shows around **24Mbps** downstream, but I get only the speed of **1Mbps** (*112kb/sec*).

I purchased **1Mbps**, but I wonder why the modem shows **24Mbps** downstream ?

Is it possible to access that whole speed ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can access the full speed. Pay for the difference.

Connection speed is just the back-end analog link quality, your speed is throttled separately.

Comment: You mean, the downstream speed is local area speed?

Comment: @DawodKhan Essentially, yes. It's the connection from your modem to the ISP local "box" that should be relatively nearby.